# Customising the fields of drop-downs in Django w.r.t to conditions

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a scenario where I have 2 drop-downs and the values of second drop-downs are based on the first drop-downs values.
For example :-
According to my implementation write now it appears to be 2 separate drop-downs 
drop-down1_value 1 
drop-down1_value 2 
drop-down1_value 3

drop-down2_value 1 
drop-down2_value 2 
drop-down2_value 3 
drop-down2_value 4

What I want is the value should appear as

```
 drop-down1_value 1      drop-down2_value 1 
                         drop-down2_value 2
```

```
 drop-down1_value 2            drop-down2_value 3
                               drop-down2_value 4
```

so, basically the values of drop down 2 are dependent on the values of drop down 1.
Internally the tables are connected but I am not able to display it as required.
It has to be done something with Django forms as per my research but I am not able to do it.
Any help will be really very helpful.

```
class ClientCheckForm(forms.ModelForm):

Check_Names = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=None)
Client_Name = forms.ModelChoiceField( queryset=Clients.objects.all(), initial=0)
Sub_Check_Names = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple,queryset=None)

class Meta:
    model = Client_Check
    fields =  "__all__"
    widgets = {
        'Client_Name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'Check_Names': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        'Sub_Check_Names':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
       }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ClientCheckForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Check_Names'].queryset = Check_Types.objects.all()
    self.fields['Client_Name'].empty_label = "Select"
    self.fields['Sub_Check_Names'].queryset = SubChecks.objects.all()
```

Comment: Where is the condition given? In your view/backend or on user interaction on the frontend? Please share some more code

Comment: Hey , I have edited the code and displayed my forms code that I have used for rendering the form. I don't know how to write the condition in order to display the drop-downs according to the conditions.

Answer (score -1):

You must add click event to drop-down1 and then your form make render again. Or using ajax you should fill the drop-down2.

Comment: Hey, can you please elaborate using some example or any links that i can follow to implement.